# Separate operations on groups of time series values identified by same flag in R

Tags: r, group-by, time-series, flags

Does anyone have a solution to perform

- separate operations on
- groups of consecutive values that are a
- subset of a time series and are
- identified by a reoccurring, identical flag
- with R ?

In the example data set created by the code below, this would refer for example to calculating the mean of “value” separately for each group where “flag” == 1 on consecutive days.

A typical case in science would be a data set recorded by an instrument that repeatedly executes a calibration procedure and flags the corresponding data with the same flag, but the user needs to evaluate each calibration separately with the same procedure.

Thanks for your suggestions. Jens

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
    date = seq(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd("2018-06-29"), by = "days"),
    flag = rep( c(rep(1,10), rep(0, 20)), 6),
    value = seq(1,180,1)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table` function `rleid`  is great for giving group IDs to runs of consecutive values. I continue to use `data.table`, but you could everything but the `rleid` part just as well in `dplyr` or `base`.

My answer comes down to *use `data.table::rleid` and then pick your favorite way to [take the mean by group (R-FAQ link)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061).*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, r_id := rleid(flag)]
df[flag == 1, list(
    min_date = min(date),
    max_date = max(date),
    mean_value = mean(value)
  ), by = r_id]

#    r_id   min_date   max_date mean_value
# 1:    1 2018-01-01 2018-01-10        5.5
# 2:    3 2018-01-31 2018-02-09       35.5
# 3:    5 2018-03-02 2018-03-11       65.5
# 4:    7 2018-04-01 2018-04-10       95.5
# 5:    9 2018-05-01 2018-05-10      125.5
# 6:   11 2018-05-31 2018-06-09      155.5
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for and perfectly does the job. Thank you so much, @Gregor !